# Extension of sum of squares

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

given $n=a^2+b^2$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$

if $n$ is odd, how do I prove that each prime divisor of $n$ is congruent to $1 \bmod 4$?

I tried to do it by proving they can't be $3 \bmod 4$ but I've been very stuck. I feel like it has something to do with the fact that $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)=1$ but I cant seem to put that together. Seems like a simple problem but I've been trying stuff for over an hour with little progress.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime dividing $a^2+b^2$, the step you really want to do is to change $a^2+b^2\equiv0\pmod p$ to $(ab^{-1})^2\equiv-1\pmod p$. Can you show that $b$ is invertible modulo $p$?

Comment: Yes! That actually helped a ton. I think i totally got it now. since (ab^-1)=-1 mod p, p must be 1 mod 4

Comment: Great, nice going!